# Create alias referencing to a part of the table

Tags: python, web2py

Consider the following database structure:

```
from gluon import DAL, Field

db = DAL('sqlite:memory:') 

db.define_table('party',
    Field('place')
)

db.define_table('participant',
    Field('party_id', 'reference party'),
    Field('name'),
    Field('role')
)    

db.party.insert(place="Jane's home")

db.participant.insert(name='Jane',party_id=1,role='host')
db.participant.insert(name='George',party_id=1,role='organizer')
db.participant.insert(name='John',party_id=1,role='guest')
db.participant.insert(name='Mary',party_id=1,role='guest')
```

Now. I would like to make a selection where I select each party with it's host and organizer.

I can do it like this:

```
host = db.participant.with_alias('host')
organizer = db.participant.with_alias('organizer')

rows = db().select(
        db.party.place,
        host.name,
        organizer.name,
    left=(
        host.on((host.party_id==db.party.id) & (host.role=='host')),
        organizer.on((organizer.party_id==db.party.id) & (organizer.role=='organizer'))
    )
)

for row in rows:
    print [row.party.place, row.host.name, row.organizer.name]
```

But I think this is not the best way. In particular this sentence:

```
& (host.role=='host')
```

Sounds pretty ridiculous. Furthermore, maybe next time I have to select all hosts. Then I have to be including the above condition everywhere.

Is there a way to define the host alias so that i get only the persons who are hosts?

I am looking for some solution like:

```
create view host as select * from participant where role = 'host'
```

Also any other ideas to make the last selection prettier are welcome!

Comment: Anybody? Does my question even make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking through `pydoc gluon.DAL` and I found that you can do this:

```
db.executesql("CREATE VIEW host AS SELECT * FROM participant WHERE role = 'host'")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but how am I supposed to use this view on my queries then? It seems to work if I just copy the participant table definition and replace the word participant with host. I was kind of looking for a way to do this in python instead of going to database level. And "if not exists" need to be specified as well.

Comment: @Pekka You're basically supposed to use it however you want, the only reason I gave you this particular sql command is because that's the one you asked about in you're question. Also, this is very pythonic, because as the saying goes ***simple is better than complex***